# How to solve analytically a Volterra integral equation of the first kind with an $\arcsin$ kernel function?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, integral-equations, integral-transforms

I am trying to find analytical solution of the below integral equation (resulting from an elasticity problem)
$$
\int_0^R \arcsin \left( \frac{t}{R} \right) \phi(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = \frac{2-R^2}{(1+R^2)^{5/2}} \, . 
$$

Here $\phi(t)$ is the unknown function and $R$ is a positive finite real number.

It would be great if someone here could provide with some useful hints/ideas that may help a bit.

Cheers

Fede

Comment: Did you try differentiating with respect to $R$?

Comment: @Ranc OK I will try this.

Comment: @Ranc Differentiation with respect to $R$ leads to $-\int_0^R \frac{t}{R(R^2-t^2)^{1/2}} \phi(t) \, \mathrm{d}t + \frac{\pi}{2} \phi(R) = \frac{3R(R^2-4)}{(1+R^2)^{7/2}}$ which more transparent but of the second kind..

Comment: I have noticed that $\phi(t)=\frac{48 t (1-t^2)}{\pi (1+t^2)^4}$ balances the RHS of the equation, but the term $\frac{\pi}{2} \phi(R)$ remains!!

Comment: maybe your boundary conditions are as such that you can set $\phi(R)=0$?

Comment: @tired Yes. That is it. In fact $\phi$ is in fact related to the displacement field of an elastic plate which is fixed at the extremities at $R$. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: @tired However this conditions $\phi(R)=0$ cannot be satisfied by the solution $\phi(t) = \frac{48t(1-t^2)}{\pi (1+t^2)^4}$ stated above. This problem is indeed puzzling..

Comment: The term $\frac{\pi}{2} \phi(R)$ is however required to obtain the solution of the original equation. In this way $\int_0^R \frac{48t(1-t^2)}{\pi (1+t^2)^4} \arcsin \left( \frac{t}{R} \right) \, \mathrm{d}t - \frac{2(3R^2-1)}{(1+R^2)^3} = \frac{2-R^2}{(1+R^2)^{5/2}}$.

Comment: Finally the solution of the above equation is written as $\phi(t) = \frac{48t(1-t^2)}{\pi (1+t^2)^4} - \frac{4(3R^2-1)}{(\pi-2) R(1+R^2)^3}$.

Comment: @tired can you confirm the above result to be true? Is there a way to getting there more technically? Thanks.

Comment: to be honest, i am not an expert on integral equations. but the form of the kernel after differentiation resembles the weightfunction for chebyshev polynomials so this might be a direction to look up for an more construtive way of solving this problem.

Comment: @tired OK. I will dig into that further.